# Carrierwave mongoid minimagick

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid, carrierwave, minimagick

I know a lot of questions have been asked but can not find an answer and how to fix my problem. I want to resize the image on the first upload, but it is not working. I can load the image properly without resizing it. 
The problem is when I add process :resize_to_fit => [300, -1]

I have a rails 4 app with the gem

```
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'carrierwave-mongoid', :require => 'carrierwave/mongoid'
gem 'fog'
gem 'mini_magick'
gem 'mongoid', '~> 4.0.0.beta1'
```

the image_uploader.rb

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  storage :fog

  process :resize_to_fit => [300, -1]

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
  process :resize_to_fit => [300, -1]
```

to

```
process :scale => [200, 300] #specify whatever width and height you want there and try
```

Sorry you need to add this method in uploader

```
 def scale(width, height)
     # do something
   end
```

Comment: It gives me the following error message NoMethodError at /startups
undefined method `scale' for #<ImageUploader:0x007fe9a341d1d0>

Comment: The code is not breaking now (thank you), but it does not seems that the image is resized, basically I have an image that is 2.6MB and I would like to reduce. The image loads but same size. @anusha

Comment: @Chleo: Try like this `version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_limit => [200, 200]
  end`

Comment: the problem by creating a thumb is that i need to amend all the existing photo already loaded in the database, and need also to amend the view to display a thumb. That is why I was looking for a way to load to S3 directly a photo that was smaller

Comment: @Chleo: You can use `resize_to_limit` property without creating thumb also

Comment: process :resize_to_limit => [20, 30] is not working and gives me an error, do I have have to define it as well ?

Comment: @Chleo: Check this link it may be useful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12391443/carrierwave-scale-image-if-the-size-is-larger-than-conditionally-create-versio